# Unable to get object value from response body in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, web-api-testing

I am a beginner to Cypress and I am trying to get hands-on in API Testing for Cypress.
I am trying a very basic `GET` response from the following URL:
https://automationexercise.com/api/productsList

I am trying to get `responseCode`, but whenever I try to object, I get blank value on it..
my logic is following:

```
it("Verify All Product response contains correct keys and values", () => {

    cy.request("GET","https://automationexercise.com/api/productsList").then((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
        expect(response.body).length.to.be.greaterThan(1)
        cy.log(response.body.responseCode)
  });
});
```

I have edited with screenshot of my result:
[image]
Let me know, where I am making a mistake.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to log and attach it in the question which you get when you do `cy.log(response.body)`.

Comment: I have added screenshot for that..

Comment: What is `responseCode` that you are logging? Can't see it in the screenshot.

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: `responseCode` is a key in this object, which I am trying to access. But can't. You can access the URL directly as well.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `cy.log()` for debugging, use `console.log()`.

If you open up a browser (not in Cypress), open the devtools, go to Network and turn on recording.

Then put your URL into the navigation box - the devtools shows you the network request and you can inspect the response in the **Response** sub-tab.

From that, you can see there is no `body` in the path, so don't add it in your test.

[image]

Comment: The reason, why I am using `cy.log()` is to make sure that I am parsing in the right way. Also, I got your point, I have used without body, trying to work with response only, and yet can't the value. Means I am still there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. `cy.log()` does not do any parsing.

Comment: And we still don't know what the actual problem is - can you clarify your question please.

Comment: I want to get the value of `responseCode` which is displaying the response of end point, the logic, which I have put in my question is not showing me that value... That's my question and the problem is..